# Deleting old backup in Thinkvantage

Tags: backup, thinkpad

i have an R61 laptop and the automatic backups are filling up my HDD.  I've seen the question on here elsewhere, but the common answer does not apply to my situation. I do not have and Advanced mode in Rescue and Recovery where i can select and delete an old backup.

How do I delete the old backups?

Comment: @Paul: I think a ThinkVantage tag is uneccessary, as ThinkPad can be used instead.

Comment: @paradroid - not a problem, I agree!

Answer (score 2):

In order to see the advanced tab, you must not run R&R from the Productivity Center, as you don't get the full menu.

Instead, start the program from `All Programs->Thinkvantage-Rescue and Recovery`, and you'll see the advanced menu at the bottom left. Now follow this knowledgebase article:

http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/X-Series-ThinkPad-Laptops/How-to-Remove-Backup-files-in-Rescue-amp-Recovery/ta-p/272821